# Reshape Error "ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required."

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

- First calculate the mid prices from the highest and lowest

```
high_prices = df.loc[:,'High'].to_numpy()
low_prices = df.loc[:,'Low'].to_numpy()
mid_prices = (high_prices+low_prices)/2.0
train_data = mid_prices[:11000]
test_data = mid_prices[11000:]
```

- Scale the data to be between 0 and 1
- When scaling remember! You normalize both test and train data with respect to training data because you are not supposed to have access to test data

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1,1)
test_data = test_data.reshape(-1,1)
```

- Train the Scaler with training data and smooth data

```
smoothing_window_size = 200
for di in range (0,1000,smoothing_window_size):
    scaler.fit(train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:])
    train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:] = caler.transform(train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:])
```

- You normalize the last bit of remaining data

```
scaler.fit(train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:])
train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:] = scaler.transform(train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:])
```

- Reshape both train and test data

```
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1)
```

- Normalize test data

```
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data).reshape(-1) #this line generates the error
```

Normalize test data from an Array

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421626/valueerror-found-array-with-0-sample-s-shape-0-1-while-a-minimum-of-1-is) the exact same question and the exact same code?